# Meteor create user without verification

Tags: meteor

I want to create a user without doing the verification, it’s set on false as soon as i create a user.

Is there a way that when i does the register the emails.verified will be set on TRUE and not false ?

Comment: Is there a problem with verified being false regarding your app?

Comment: I want it as soon as i register the email.verified will be set as true and not false.
because i'm doing an autologin after the register.

Comment: I understand your question, what I mean is: is some functionality - like your autologin - failing and you think it is caused by verified being false?

Comment: No, for the moment i'm trying to do a request of register, and the email.verified is by default after the POST Request is set to false, i just need it to be at false.

Comment: I don't see the purpose of setting it to true plus I rather see issues in the future when your application grows and suddenly you need a working email verification system. Maybe I misunderstand your use case. If so, please extend your question with some details.

Comment: @Jankapunkt is it possible to set it to true on the register ? I'm doing some tests.

Answer (score 1):

Place this code on the server, assuming you have only one email

```
AccountsTemplates.configure({postSignUpHook: postSignUp});

const postSignUp = function postSignUp(userId, info) {
  Meteor.users.update(userId, {
        $set: {
          "emails.0.verified": true
        }
      });  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code on server side should do the trick:

```
   Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
      user.emails[0].verified = true;
      return user;
   })
```